# Receiving login shell data via serial port

Tags: raspbian, usb, serial, login

I'm writing code to send data to and from a raspberry pi (pi zero running raspbian lite) via serial port, using 1 python script on either side.
I've set everything up so that I can use `port='/dev/ttyGS0'` from the pi and `port='COM17'` on my windows pc.

It seems to work at first, though after a while the connection on the side of the pi gets interrupted with the following error

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: read failed: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

Meanwhile on the windows side I'm receiving data that implies the login shell is coming trough the serial port:

```
\r\nRaspian GNU/Linux 10 rasperrypi ttyGS0\r\n\r\nrasperrypi login:
\r\r\npassword:
```

I'm guessing I have to turn off the login shell over serial, though I can't seem to find anything relevant to this problem online.
I can post the python scripts if needed, though I doubt I'm doing anything wrong on that side.

**EDIT**

I was also experiencing problems with write/read permissions to `ttyGS0`, though this problem could be fixed by adding my user to the dialout group: `sudo usermod -a -G dialout pi` this did NOT solve the main issue though

I also tried disable the console trough `cmdline.txt` and `raspi-config` this did not change anything.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101921/discussion-on-question-by-user2536665-receiving-login-shell-data-via-serial-port).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find the issue;

It seems I had a specific service enabled on my pi that was messing with the serial output, namely `getty@ttyGS0.service` This service is indeed intended to provide console over serial.
I fixed the issue by simply disabling and stopping it

```
sudo systemctl disable getty@ttyGS0.service
sudo systemctl stop getty@ttyGS0.service
```

Comment: This is good since this is I think a relatively recent practice on Raspbian that will catch other new users.

Comment: Is there something wrong with using raspi-config? The bootcmd option enables the serial port, but raspi-config->advanced->serial (A7) disables the login shell over serial and may require restart.

Comment: @crasic
I was using raspbian-buster-lite on a pi zero, and tried disabling login shell over serial via 
rasp-config>Interfacing options>Serial>Disable serial login shell 
this indeed did not stop the problem until I had manually disabled the service in question